# Can a logged in user logon Windows on another computer (that has the same credentials)?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, command-line, credentials

I'm programming in c# (form application),

I have 2 PC's and both have Windows 8.1

They are exactly the same machines, with the same username and the same password.

So only a different ip and mac address.

When I boot, I need to logon into windows with a password.
As well for the first pc as for the second pc.

so when 1 off the pc's is booted (doesn't matter which one).

I have to use my password to logon into Windows (both pc's have the same username and password).

On this moment I configured a form application that run's when when I am logged into Windows.

This program ping to my 2 pc's.
so the program knows which one is online.
Then it sends a WakeOnLan to the pc that is still powered off.
It works (easy), and after some seconds I ping again.
when both pc's are online,
this program will check which pc is logged in by using managementScope.

My Question:

Is it possible to logon windows on the pc that isn't logged in (after the check)?

it may be with PowerShell or if possible c# form
or a cmd or bat file or something else...

How can I do this?

Comment: Question lacks clarity. It would be good if you can ask your query directly

Comment: lol, i know the question is difficult to ask clearly, i gess the question is clearly. What i want to do is that my pc logon automaticly if the other pc is logged in. so when i logon into my pc and it see's that the other pc is not logged in. it wil send "a query" with credentials to logon from remote. better ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use invoke-command on you remote computer and execute commands

[example here](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-remote-management,2-781.html)

Comment: yes maybe i could do that. @ the start of programming this software, i was thinking to set a script on both computers. And when windows is starting up (before logging on) it will check if 1 of the 2 computers is online and logged in automaticly . but i have no clu about let a pc loggon automaticly. Do i need tot start a service or... ? or can i let a script run on the computer that is logged in, so it can send his credentials to the computer that has to loggon. because i use the same credentials.